# What kind of samples do I have

Tags: independence, sample

I am attempting to discover through surveying something about the population of beer drinkers in a country.

I carry out a nationally representative survey asking questions about awareness of beer and knowledge.

I then ask the same questions at a one-week course on everything to do with beer and also beermaking. I ask these questions at the beginning and at the end of the course and see a pre/ post difference. I also compare the baseline answers between the national survey and the survey questions asked at the course.

In this scenario I am trying to understand  the correct terminology for describing the two groups (survey asked in the two settings) because this has implications for statistical testing. My population is beer drinkers, i.e anyone who drinks beer at all including those who drink lager once a week to those who go to real ale festivals.

Naturally my two samples are very different - not least because one is more likely to be more passionate and knowledgeable from the beginning and the other is a bigger population.

I wanted to ask whether my two samples would be described as independent, and also whether this scenario could count as a a type of experiment - with an intervention (beer course attendance) being administered to one group but not the other?

Finally, what are the implications for what tests are appropriate to determine the efficacy of the intervention?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description it sounds like you have two separate research questions: **(1)** How does a randomly sampled, nationally representative group of beer drinkers compare to a randomly sampled group of beer drinkers *interested in taking a course on beer* and **(2)** Does your one-week course on beer affect one's awareness of beer?

For the first research question you have a cross-sectional design with two groups. Regarding their independence, is it possible that subjects in the nationally representative group made it into the one-week course group? If no (in your sample), then more precisely your nationally representative group is "a nationally representative group of beer-drinkers who are not interested in participating in a one-week beer course."

For the second research question, I would say you have a quasi-experimental, one-group pretest-posttest design.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for engaging with this question! Your summary is spot on. Just a few extra details for you - the course attendees are not randomly sampled - they are people who voluntarily signed up and the only thing we do know about them is that they drink some amount of beer already. It is possible but unlikely there would be group overlap but I would say let's imagine several individuals at least do overlap. What would that mean?

Comment: Also, let's imagine that the beer course is hosted in a really small and hard to reach town, to the extent that many people who might have attended decided against it. There's potential overlap but because of logistics the groups end up entirely separate. Would that change how we define our sample? My biggest question is about the implications of the course sample not being random. Does that destroy all validity?

Comment: @H.R.Badger, glad this helps. If you feel as though your question is answered, will you please accept my answer?

Regarding your follow-up questions, the short answer is "no, it does not destroy all validity." What is important is for you to be very clear about the populations from which you sampled and the potential for overlap, even if it did not happen in your study. In terms of statistical analysis, you can use techniques to model in non-independence. One such approach would be to use structural equation modeling, but there are many.